# Google Signed URL in Google Cloud Module Android. (Signature Fails)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully managed to generate Signed URL to "GET" objects from the bucket using service account xxxxxxxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com and when I change the service account to 
xxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com it fails to generate "GET" signed URL too.

I am unable to generate "PUT" Signed URL with any service account and I guess it needs some special roles to service account or bucket which I think I already have given.

Comment: Even gsutil fails to generate "PUT" URL.

Comment: When you say "it fails to generate", what is "it"? `gsutil`? If not, can you provide a pointer to code?